# install rxtx under JDK

Tags: installation, jdk, sms

A java developer who want to send SMS ,may use [SMSLib](https://github.com/smslib/smslib) project.

SMSLib requires to set up :

- `javacomm` library (if it is windows plateform)
- `rxtx` library (if it is linux plateform ) 
  by adding it in JDK library
  [See documentation](https://github.com/smslib/smslib/blob/dev/doc/UsingGSMModems.md)

**My question  is :** 
How can i set up RxTx library under ubuntu ?

http://www.rxtx.org

http://www.jcontrol.org/download/readme_rxtx_en.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ou can use the command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install librxtx-java
```

It simple download the files to your system, but Java not know where is it! To work with installed RxTx, you have to setup Build Path to compile the code, and copy the binaries (.so files) to java library path.

To learn how to do it please check [this](http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2013/06/setup-rxtx-jar-and-so-for-ubuntu.html).